# Instances not communicating across Availability Zones within a single region

Tags: amazon-web-services, availability-zone

I have the following instances, they are in the same VPC and region but different AZs, both of them are in the same SecurityGroup.

Subnets:

- us-west-2a         **instance-a**   172.31.32.0/20
- us-west-2b         **instance-b**   172.31.16.0/20

These two instances are not able to communicate with each other. What do I need to do to enable communication between these two AZs?

Here is the main route: 
[image]

Subnet 1:
[image: Subnet 1]

Subnet 2:
[image: Subnet 2]

Comment: Check the routing tables of the subnets or post the routing table entries.

Comment: @helloV updated the  question with route info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the needed ports in the SecurityGroups of the EC2s. You should also look into your subnets and the routing tables of these subnets or your VPC.

Comment: both of them are in the same security group does

Comment: I was working with the assumption that since both instances are using the same securityGroup , the issue had to be routing table but . even if they are with in the same security group, i had to open ports  by self referencing the security group .